# Tengo en un arreglo los siguientes numeros: 1 2 7 4 6 7 8 Como hago para insertar el 0?

Tags: python, vectores

Tengo en un vector y por ejemplo que los siguientes numeros que ponga sean: 1 2 7 4 6 7 8 Como hago para insertar el 0 luego de un numero par ? o sea que me quede lo siguiente: 1 2 0 7 4 0 6 0 7 8 0, pero sin usar ningun string

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué intentaste? En [este enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) encontrarás información útil si todavía no intentaste nada. Luego edita la pregunta mostrando lo que hiciste para que sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una de las posibles soluciones a tu algoritmo:

```
# importación de modulo
import numpy as np

# creación del array númerico
my_array = np.array([1,2,7,4,6,7,8])
#print(type(my_array) --> OUTPUT: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

# Creación lista vacía para poder agregar la secuencia de números deseada
new_array = []
#print(type(new_array)) --> OUTPUT:<class 'list'>
# Con un FOR LOOP recorremos todos los elementos dentro de nuestro array inicial
for num in my_array:
    # Si el número de esta iteración NO ES par: agregamos el número a la lista
    new_array.append(num) if num % 2 != 0 else 0
    # Si el número de esta iteración ES par: agregamos el número a la lista + el número 0
    if num % 2 == 0:
        new_array.append(num) 
        new_array.append(0)

#print(new_array) --> OUTPUT: [1, 2, 0, 7, 4, 0, 6, 0, 7, 8, 0] ||  TYPE: <class 'list'>

# Por último creamos el array deseado con su tipo de dato correspondiente e imprimos el array final:
final_array = np.array(new_array)
print(final_array)
# --> OUTPUT: [1 2 0 7 4 0 6 0 7 8 0] ||  TYPE:<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Puede quedar más simple quitando `if num % 2 != 0 else 0` y la línea `new_array.append(num)` del ` if num % 2 == 0`.